# Ember-simple-auth with ember-cli-simple-auth-token

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying to use ember-simple-auth with ember-cli-simple-auth-token:

```
"ember-cli-simple-auth-token": "^0.7.3",
"ember-simple-auth": "1.0.1"
```

And that's my configurations:

```
  ENV['simple-auth-token'] = {
    authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:token',
    identificationField: 'email',
    serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/token'
  };
```

Am i missing something? Cause i'm receiving this error in my console:

> Could not find module `simple-auth/authenticators/base` imported from `simple-auth-token/authenticators/token`

I already try to uninstall and npm prune, and reinstall.. and the same message keeps showing.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - simple-auth-token hasn't been updated as yet. A couple of minor changes seems to get it going again, which I will post to the author.

The changes in the ember-simple-auth-token module required are:

1) app/initializers/simple-auth.js:

- change "simple-auth" on line 1 to "ember-simple-auth" and
- remove (or comment out) lines 2 and 9 (the import for setup, and the call

to setup).

2) addon/authenticators/token.js:
   change "simple-auth" on line 2 to "ember-simple-auth"

3) addon/authorizers/token.js:
   change :simple-auth" on line 2 to "ember-simple-auth"

Hopefully that helps a few people out there struggling with this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the addon is `ember-simple-auth` and it's looking for a path `simple-auth/authenticators/base` which should be `ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base`. You should correct that import in the file `simple-auth-token/authenticators/token`.

Comment: i dont have this file.. should i create?

Comment: The file is in the addon `simple-auth-token` that you are using. It imports a file from the addon `ember-cli-simple-auth` but the path in that import is wrong, it should be `ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base`.

Comment: I guess ember-cli-simple-auth-token hasn't been updated yet to work with Ember Simple Auth 1.0.